# Differing error templates for dev and production in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, templates, error-handling, twig

Following the docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html I have been able to add my own template for errors;

```
app
 |- Resources
 |  | - TwigBundle
 |  |  |- view
 |  |  |  |- Exception
 |  |  |  |  |- exception.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error400.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error404.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error500.html.twig
 |  |  |  |- layout.html.twig
 |- config
```

This works perfectly, but how do I keep the stack traces and the detailed errors for my dev environment?

In production I wish to use my own templates, in the dev environment I wish to use Symfony2's own templates.

Comment: I have just been doing the same last night and as far as I could see on `Symfony2` (`v2.5`) still threw "green" alien page with complete stacktrace, while I was in `dev` mode. However, if I move to `prod`, my custom error page is shown instead.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case for me, hmmm. have you set up your templates the same as me within `app`?

Comment: Similarly, I only had `error403.html.twig`. Do you use `Symfony 2.6` on something else? They have made some things easier with previewing error pages as of `2.6`.

Comment: `2.5`, I have error and exception. Does 403 get overridden in dev mode for you?

Comment: If `dev` no, but in `prod` yes. At one point I wished that was the case as it really slowed down the testing of `error403.html.twig` layout (had to `cache:clear` after each change...)

Comment: Did you define your own exception handler? Maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: I didn't, I think I need this https://github.com/webfactory/exceptions-bundle

Comment: Yes, I think they have even mentioned this package in official docs. However, I wouldn't hold my breath for it to solve this problem, but merely to ease the creation of error pages

Comment: Would upgrading be silly of me?

Comment: Hah, well, ultimately - no! But beware, `Symfony 2.6` introduced some changes to `security.context`. You might want to read `UPGRADE` doc before deciding. Can you update your question with the contents of your `config.yml`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69825/discussion-between-jake-n-and-jovan-perovic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app
 |- Resources
 |  |- TwigBundle
 |  |  |- view
 |  |  |  |- Exception
 |  |  |  |  |- exception.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error400.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error404.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error500.html.twig
 |  |  |  |- layout.html.twig
 |  |- view
 |  |  |- my_custom_error_layout.html.twig
 |- config
```

<kbd>my_custom_error_layout.html.twig</kbd>

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
html, block, whatnot go here
</body>
</html>
```

<kbd>error400.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends "::my_custom_error_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
details or fixed message go here...
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In our recent project we implement a custom [ExceptionListener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) configured as above:

```
    <!-- Acme Exception Listener -->
    <service id="kernel.listener.customer_area_exception_listener" class="AcmeSecurityBundle\Listener\AcmeExceptionListener">
        <argument type="service" id="templating" />
        <argument>%acme.exceptions.debug%</argument>
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.exception" method="onKernelException" />
    </service>
```

With a parameter (from `parameters.yml` ) for differentiate the behaviour in the env.

The exception listener know how render every type of Exception, custom Exception also.

Hope this help